# Remove credit on pressing a button PHP MySQL AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to make a simple credit page where people have that much credit, and by clicking on a button next to their name it will remove on credit

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Name</td><td>Massages left</td>
</tr>

<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","dbuser","password");
mysql_select_db("db");

$command = "select pass_name, credit_left from pass;";
$result  = mysql_query($command);

//If there is, list that particular entry
while ($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)) 
{
    print "<tr><td>" . $data->pass_name . "</td>" . 
          "<td>" . $data->credit_left . "</td></tr>\n"
    // Button here that you click and make credit go down one;
}

?>
</table>
```

For example it will say Ben - 2credits - click here to remove one.

Thanks

EDIT

okay here is what I have:
the script is

```
<script>
function removeOneCredit(str)

{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("credit").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","removeonecredit.php"+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

the form is:

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    print "<TR><TD>".$data->pass_name."</TD><TD id='credit'>".$data->credit_left."</TD><TD><form><input type='submit' value='- 1' onsubmit='removeOneCredit(?pass_id=".$data->pass_id."&credit_left=".$data->credit_left.")'></form></TD></TR>\n";

}
```

the removeonecredit.php is

```
<html>
<?php

$pass_id = $_GET[pass_id];
$credit_left = $_GET[credit_left]-1;
//change value
mysql_connect("localhost","user","pw");
mysql_select_db("db");
$command = "update pass set credit_left='$credit_left' where pass_id='$pass_id';";
mysql_query($command);
//now print value
mysql_connect("localhost","user","pw");
mysql_select_db("db");
$command = "select credit_left from pass where pass_id='$pass_id';";
$result = mysql_query($command);
$data = mysql_fetch_object($result);
echo $data->credit_left;



?>

</html>
```

If I pass the string manually at the end of removeonecredit.php, it works, so it must be the Ajax part of things...

Comment: OK, so what's your question? Be specific.

Comment: Well what sort of code would you use? Should I create a form that sends a sql query to make "credit_left minus one" and reload? If yes, how do I apply that query to just that one user (the while iterates through my users)

Comment: I don't understand why you're passing the pass_id and credit_left to the AJAX function that way. You shouldn't really be passing that sort of information. You should be figuring that out in your removeonecredit.php file using sessions. The way you're doing it right now is very dangerous and insecure. Anyway, you can get rid of  the action attribute from your form temporarily to test your AJAX function. Otherwise it might override the AJAX code.

Comment: I'm not worried about security here I just want to do it simple

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Anyway, you can get rid of the action attribute from your form temporarily to test your AJAX function. Otherwise it might override the AJAX code

Comment: Are you editing this website live? If so, send me a link so I can help you more effectively.

Comment: I am but its all password protected. If you have a look at my latest code, I have just <form> without action. Like I said if I input the data manually in the url of removeonecredit.php it works so it must be the ajax side of things.

Answer (score 0):

Use a from with a button and use an AJAX script in JavaScript to update the database without reloading the page. If you don't care that the page reloads, then you can just use the form but you don't have to write the AJAX script. To update the database for a single user, you can iterate through your database, and find the user you are looking for by a unique identifier such as an id, or a username:

For example, using the `UPDATE` MySQL command:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET credits_left='1'
WHERE username='Bob'
```

So this will update the credits value only for the person with username 'Bob'.
I know this isn't very specific, but if you make your question more specific, I might be able to help you better.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've setup my table with a pass_id, I suppose we could use that?

Comment: so it would be "update pass set credit_left where pass_id=".$data->pass_id.";"

Comment: Is your pass_id unique for every user? If so, then yes, it would be appropriate. Make sure you make pass_id the 'primary index' (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html). This is very easy if you are using phpMyAdmin for your database. If you make it a primary index, MySQL guarantees that it will not allow duplicates for pass_id. Yes, that query should work.

Comment: yes pass_id is primary key. not sure about the rest, do I make a button with a onclick handler?

Comment: Yes, you can create a simple form with a submit type button inside. Use an "onsubmit" handler to a javascript function that will handle the event. In this function, you can use AJAX to call a PHP script without reloading the page (http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example.asp) or, you can just use the action attribute of the form to link it directly to the PHP script, but it will reload the page in that case which might be inconvenient. Also, in your query, it should be "set credit_left='some_value'".

Comment: `<script>
function removeOneCredit(str)
{
xmlhttp.open("POST","passes.php?pass_id="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>`

Comment: that's for the script and then `while ($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    print "<TR><TD>".$data->pass_name."</TD><TD>".$data->credit_left."</TD><TD><form action='passes.php' method='post'><input type='submit' value='- 1' onsubmit='removeOneCredit(".$data->pass_id.")'></TD></TR>\n";
 
}`

Comment: and I have to create a php page that send the MySQL query to the pass_id passed in the url right?

Comment: `<html>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","dbuser","pw");
mysql_select_db("db");
$command = "update pass set credit_left where pass_id=".$POST[pass_id].";";
$result = mysql_query($command);


?>

</html>`

Comment: You get the credit using a MySQL query first and save it in a variable. Then you subtract one from that variable and update it in the database. Yes, you have to create a separate PHP page to handle the request.

Comment: Must be something wrong with my Ajax code `<script>
function removeOneCredit(str)
{
xmlhttp.open("POST","removeonecredit.php"+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>`    the string being `?pass_id=".$data->pass_id."?credit_left=".$data->credit_left."` that works well I checked the resulting code

Comment: Should be "GET" not "POST". Change that in your html form as well. It looks like you're missing other code as well. Check the link I gave you earlier, it has plenty of examples.

Comment: I have edited my initial question with the code I have now. in the form, should I link to the actual page it's on or the page where the AJAX is linking to??

Answer (score 0):

turns out the = in the function arguments is a problem, I posted a question on how to escape it here: [Javascript escape a equal sign PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794271/javascript-escape-a-equal-sign-php)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make that change using PHP, you would have to make a form and submit to the same page. PHP renders code on the server and sends HTML to the client (the user on the computer). If you want it to be reflected in the database, you would have to run a mysql query to update that field. Then once the form is submitted, the top of the page can process it, and the new output would be loaded.

Another option would be to use javascript. In this case it would not be necessary to reload the page.

```
<script>
var count = 2;
$(document).on('click', '#clickButton', function(){
    $('#countDiv').text(count--);
});
</script>
```

And your html/php page would have to have a button with `id="clickButton"` and a div like `<div id="countDiv"></div>`

I didn't test this out. But I hope it helps or takes you in the right direction!

Comment: Hi thanks for that, but the javascript wouldnt update the data in the SQL db would it?

Comment: No, it wouldn't... it would only change it on the page. To make an update to the db via javascript you would have to make an ajax request to another page for example api.php that would run the update and return success or fail.