# Javascript escape a equal sign PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have the following code:

```
print "<TR><TD>".$data->pass_name."</TD><TD><span id='credit'>".$data->credit_left."</span></TD><TD><input type='button' value='- 1' onclick='removeOneCredit(pass_id\=".$data->pass_id."&credit_left\=".$data->credit_left.");'></TD></TR>\n";
```

where I am trying to escape the equal so it gets passed in the function as it need to be a query in the url (the rendered code will be like this:

```
<input type='button' value='- 1' onclick='removeOneCredit(pass_id\=5&credit_left\=2");'>
```

But I keep getting errors that the \ that I use to escape my  = is invalid. How would I escape my = so it can be passed into the argument of my js function?

Thank you

Comment: what you trying to acheive with this ? onclick should have correct javascript syntax...

Comment: I *don't* think you need to escape the equal sign.

Comment: I am passing a query strings as an argument to an ajax function that passes that argument into a url that a php file executes

Comment: If I don't escape the equal sign I get errors "invalid left hand side arguments"

Comment: What you need to do is to quote the query string, like @Musa's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape the `=`, what you need to do is quote the string.

```
print "<TR><TD>".$data->pass_name."</TD><TD><span id='credit'>".$data->credit_left."</span></TD>
       <TD><input type='button' value='- 1' onclick='removeOneCredit(\"pass_id=".$data->pass_id."&credit_left=".$data->credit_left."\");'></TD></TR>\n";
```

Comment: problem is in php it is part of print so I can't use double quotes: `print "<TR><TD>".$data->pass_name."</TD><TD><span id='credit'>".$data->credit_left."</span></TD><TD><input type='button' value='- 1' onclick='removeOneCredit(pass_id\=".$data->pass_id."&credit_left\=".$data->credit_left.");'></TD></TR>\n";`

Comment: @bamwebdesign You can just escape it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put quotes around the string you are passing to `removeOneCredit`

```
<input ... onclick='removeOneCredit("pass_id=5&credit_left=2");'>
```

Comment: I can't because it is inside a print statement in php (See code in original question)

Comment: @bamwebdesign: if so, you escape the quote (`\"` or `\'`), not the equals sign